# SQL user defined function returns 0 instead of float

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I want to create a function using the code below, when I run the query the value returned is

```
21902/2061=0.094101
```

code to be used as a function

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @nat_weight INT =0;
DECLARE @mattype1 INT;
DECLARE @mattype2 INT;
DECLARE @mattype3 INT;
DECLARE @CycleHopper_02 INT;
DECLARE @PRCT_VAL FLOAT;
--DECLARE @me38_cycle_data_ndx INT;
-- get material type, need only hoppers 1-3, hopper 4,5,6 material type will never = 2
SET @mattype1 = (SELECT typehopper_01 FROM mm_Cycle_Data WHERE me38_cycle_data_ndx=8002);
SET @mattype2 = (SELECT typehopper_02 FROM mm_Cycle_Data WHERE me38_cycle_data_ndx=8002);
SET @mattype3 = (SELECT typehopper_03 FROM mm_Cycle_Data WHERE me38_cycle_data_ndx=8002 );
SET @CycleHopper_02 = (SELECT CycleHopper_02 FROM mm_Cycle_Data WHERE me38_cycle_data_ndx=8002 );
-- if material type=2 then add to @nat_weight ,  
IF @mattype1 = 2
    set @nat_weight = (SELECT cyclehopper_01 FROM mm_Cycle_Data WHERE me38_cycle_data_ndx=8002 );
IF @mattype2 = 2
    set @nat_weight =@nat_weight+ (SELECT cyclehopper_02 FROM mm_Cycle_Data WHERE me38_cycle_data_ndx=8002 );
IF @mattype3 = 2
    set @nat_weight =@nat_weight+ (SELECT cyclehopper_03 FROM mm_Cycle_Data WHERE me38_cycle_data_ndx=8002 )
-- device hoper weight by natural weight,  0 if dev/0 
SET @PRCT_VAL= (SELECT COALESCE(CAST(@CycleHopper_02 AS FLOAT)/CAST(@nat_weight AS FLOAT),0));
IF @PRCT_VAL=1 
SET @PRCT_VAL=100
```

When I create the function the returned value is 0, what could be the cause of that?

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.hprpct_02(@me38_cycle_data_ndx INT)
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @nat_weight INT =0;
DECLARE @mattype1 INT;
DECLARE @mattype2 INT;
DECLARE @mattype3 INT;
DECLARE @CycleHopper_02 INT;
DECLARE @PRCT_VAL FLOAT;
--DECLARE @me38_cycle_data_ndx INT;
-- get material type, need only hoppers 1-3, hopper 4,5,6 material type will never = 2
SET @mattype1 = (SELECT typehopper_01 FROM mm_Cycle_Data WHERE me38_cycle_data_ndx=8002);
SET @mattype2 = (SELECT typehopper_02 FROM mm_Cycle_Data WHERE me38_cycle_data_ndx=8002);
SET @mattype3 = (SELECT typehopper_03 FROM mm_Cycle_Data WHERE me38_cycle_data_ndx=8002 );
SET @CycleHopper_02 = (SELECT CycleHopper_02 FROM mm_Cycle_Data WHERE me38_cycle_data_ndx=8002 );
-- if material type=2 then add to @nat_weight ,  
IF @mattype1 = 2
    set @nat_weight = (SELECT cyclehopper_01 FROM mm_Cycle_Data WHERE me38_cycle_data_ndx=8002 );
IF @mattype2 = 2
    set @nat_weight =@nat_weight+ (SELECT cyclehopper_02 FROM mm_Cycle_Data WHERE me38_cycle_data_ndx=8002 );
IF @mattype3 = 2
    set @nat_weight =@nat_weight+ (SELECT cyclehopper_03 FROM mm_Cycle_Data WHERE me38_cycle_data_ndx=8002 )
-- device hoper weight by natural weight,  0 if dev/0 
SET @PRCT_VAL= (SELECT COALESCE(CAST(@CycleHopper_02 AS FLOAT)/CAST(@nat_weight AS FLOAT),0));
IF @PRCT_VAL=1 
SET @PRCT_VAL=100
RETURN @PRCT_VAL
END
```

Comment: you are returning int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RETURNS INT` statement causes the result to be casted to the integer - 0 in this case. You want a float, so replace it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you just declare an int it will be NULL.  So this code:

```
set @nat_weight =@nat_weight+ ...
```

will evaluate to NULL if @nat_weight was not set in your first condition (IF @mattype1 = 2).

Then at the end you have:

```
SET @PRCT_VAL=(SELECT COALESCE(CAST(@CycleHopper_02 AS FLOAT)/CAST(@nat_weight AS FLOAT),0))
```

Bet if you did COALESCE(..., -13) the return value will be -13.

So initialize everything to zero that you want to default to zero.